# Can't install .cap file on NXP P71D321

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I'm having an issue with installing a .cap file on a NXP P71D321.

I'm trying to install an applet on my card using gpshell, but it says it can't open a secure channel ("Failed to open secure channel: Card cryptogram invalid!"). Can can cause the issue and how can I move forward with the installation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When using "gp -l" I'm getting:
"Failed to open secure channel: Card cryptogram invalid!
Received: 95113B65268E9A9A
Expected: 6FB83C923AA26CFC"

Comment: Same error for "gp -install applet.cap"

Comment: That sounds as if gp -l is attempting to use default keys, but your card has been personalized with a different keyset. Do you have any way to know the keys for your card?

Comment: I don't have any information regarding someone changing keys before the card arrived to me. The keyset should be the default one for the chip, which I think is 4041..4F. I think is this one because I couldn't find any other information about default keyset for this card online